# Using if statement to load a list before sending it via intent - sending 3 times

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Im trying to use if statements to load a list later send it via intent, it seems to be sending it 3 times or looping through to load the string 3 times. I have to send 2 intents to the consuming activity. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is this code executed? Could you be adding the same delegate three times?

Comment: You mention that you're unsure of the cause.  I'd start by adding some basic logging to determine what's happening - is it looping multiple times or is it sending multiple times.

Comment: I have debugged and it is looping 3 times before sending the intent.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that @DStanley is correct.  You're either adding the delegate multiple times or the event is firing multiple times.  You could try adding some additional logging to pinpoint it more accurately.

Comment: I notice your Items list isn't local - is it possible that you have an event on any of the checkboxes or the Item list itself that is causing the button click to fire as you're adding items to the list within this delegate...or even within the PercentageActivity code?

Just to clarify, when you say it's looping 3 time and then sending - you mean the delegate is being called 3 times and then the Intent fires 3 times?

Comment: I have other pages using the same code to send an intent of the same. I will change the intent names and check

Comment: Add code please

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend that you use the Select Case statement rather than If statement and I would rather go with Radio button where the user is limited to only select one option. In summary, you have two way to go around this.

Comment: Considering that he is adding an array of values based on the checkboxes, a radio button wouldnt really be appropriate - equally taking that into account it makes the use of a switch statement something not really practical

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's happening but this *might* work around it until you can figure it out.

```
// global variable
var running = false;    

btn.Click += delegate
            {

            if (!running){

                running = true;

                if (ckb1.Checked)
                {
                    Items.Add("Regretful");
                }
                if (ckb2.Checked)
                {
                    Items.Add("Empathic");
                }
                if (ckb3.Checked)
                {
                    Items.Add("Shocked");
                }
                if (ckb4.Checked)
                {
                    Items.Add("Shy");
                }
                if (ckb5.Checked)
                {
                    Items.Add("Irritated");
                }
                if (ckb6.Checked)
                {
                    Items.Add("Lazy");
                }


                string result = string.Join(",", Items.ToArray());

                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(PercentageActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
                intent.PutExtra("EmOmood", result);
                String eventType = "Medium";
                intent.PutExtra("mood", eventType);

                running = false;
            }


            };
    c# xamarin.android
    shareeditflag
```

Comment: Depending on your answer to my last comment, you may want to move the use of the 'running' variable into the PercentageActivity code...it all depends what exactly is looping.